# Jquery not performing function properly after a previews function was called

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok I'm a bit of a noob and not entirely sure how I should ask this question.

I will start by showing my code

HTML:

```
<div class="image-popup-container">
    <button id="close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
    <div id="closearea"></div>

    <ul id="image-popup" class="image-popup">
        <li class="product-image">
            <img src="http://algaecal.cloudcreations.ca/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/AlgaeCal-guarantee-7-year-square.png" alt="AlgaeCal 7 Years Guarantee" />
        </li>
        <li class="product-image">
            <img src="http://algaecal.cloudcreations.ca/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/AlgaeCal-Plus-Product-Main-Image.png" alt="AlgaeCal Plus Main Product Image" />
        </li>
        <li class="product-video">
            <iframe src="//fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/w4ithbv9tz" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="wistia_embed" name="wistia_embed" allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen width="640" height="360"></iframe>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="images">
    <div id="image-preview" data-slick-index="0">
        <img src="http://algaecal.cloudcreations.ca/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/AlgaeCal-guarantee-7-year-square.png" alt="AlgaeCal 7 Years Guarantee" />
    </div>
    <ul id="image-thumbs" class="thumbnails">
        <li class="product-image-thumbnail">
            <img src="http://algaecal.cloudcreations.ca/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/AlgaeCal-guarantee-7-year-square.png" alt="AlgaeCal 7 Years Guarantee" />
        </li>
        <li class="product-image-thumbnail">
            <img src="http://algaecal.cloudcreations.ca/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/AlgaeCal-Plus-Product-Main-Image.png" alt="AlgaeCal Plus Main Product Image" />
        </li>
        <li class="product-video-thumbnail">
            <img src="http://algaecal.cloudcreations.ca/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/AlgaeCal-Plus-Product-Main-Video-Thumbnail.jpg">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// Load Carousel of thumbnails
$('.thumbnails').slick({
    dots: false,
    prevArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev slick-arrow slick-disabled" aria-label="Previous" role="button" aria-disabled="true" style="display: block;"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></button>',
    nextArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-next slick-arrow" aria-label="Next" role="button" style="display: block;" aria-disabled="false"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>',
    infinite: false,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    centerMode: false,
    variableWidth: true
});

// Grab Preview image
var imagePreview = $("#image-preview")

// Open product video thumbnail into iframe popup
// Listen for when product-video-thumbnail is clicked
$('.product-video-thumbnail').click(function(){
    // Grab clicked product-video-thumbnail data-slick-index
    var videoData = $(this).attr('data-slick-index');

    imagePopupContainer.fadeIn();
    $('.image-popup').slick({
        centerMode: true,
        prevArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev slick-arrow slick-disabled" aria-label="Previous" role="button" aria-disabled="true" style="display: block;"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></button>',
        nextArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-next slick-arrow" aria-label="Next" role="button" style="display: block;" aria-disabled="false"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>',
        centerPadding: '60px',
        slidesToShow: 1,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 768,
                settings: {
                    arrows: false,
                    centerMode: true,
                    centerPadding: '40px',
                    slidesToShow: 3
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 480,
                settings: {
                    arrows: false,
                    centerMode: true,
                    centerPadding: '40px',
                    slidesToShow: 1
                }
            }
        ]
    });
    // Go to the correct slide
    $('.image-popup').slick('slickGoTo', videoData);
});

// Listen for when product-image-thumbnail is clicked
$('.product-image-thumbnail').click(function(){
    // Grab clicked product-image-thumbnail attributes and img attributes
    var imageSrc = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    var imageAlt = $(this).find('img').attr('alt');
    var imageData = $(this).attr('data-slick-index');

    // Fade out the preview image
    imagePreview.fadeOut( function(){
        // Change preview image src to clicked thumbnail src
        imagePreview.find('img').attr("src", imageSrc);
        // Change preview image alt to clicked thumbnail alt
        imagePreview.find('img').attr("alt", imageAlt);
        // Update the slick-index for modal popup carousel
        imagePreview.attr("data-slick-index", imageData);
    });
    // Fade the preview image back into view
    imagePreview.fadeIn();
});

var imagePopupContainer = $(".image-popup-container")

imagePreview.click(function(){
    imagePopupContainer.fadeIn();
    $('.image-popup').slick({
        centerMode: true,
        prevArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev slick-arrow slick-disabled" aria-label="Previous" role="button" aria-disabled="true" style="display: block;"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></button>',
        nextArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-next slick-arrow" aria-label="Next" role="button" style="display: block;" aria-disabled="false"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>',
        centerPadding: '60px',
        slidesToShow: 1,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 768,
                settings: {
                    arrows: false,
                    centerMode: true,
                    centerPadding: '40px',
                    slidesToShow: 3
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 480,
                settings: {
                    arrows: false,
                    centerMode: true,
                    centerPadding: '40px',
                    slidesToShow: 1
                }
            }
        ]
    });
    var index = $("#image-preview").attr("data-slick-index");
    alert(index);
    $('.image-popup').slick('slickGoTo', index);
})

$("#closearea").click(function(){
    imagePopupContainer.fadeOut();

});
$("#close").click(function(){
    imagePopupContainer.fadeOut();
});
});
```

You can see this currently in action here http://algaecal.cloudcreations.ca/

When you click on the Image preview it should pop an alert box howing the `data-slick-index` value, then open the fullsize preview-image. If you close the fullsize image and clicked a different thumbnail, that will update the preview image to the clicked thumbnail. Then if you click on the updated preview image it should show an alert box and then the updated preview image, however it is showing the previous preview image and no alert box.

I have no idea why this is happening. Its like after the first jquery function is performed the DOM is updated and the next jquery function performed does not grab the correct `data-slick-index' from the DOM and does not do the alert.

I'm terribly sorry for this poorly worded question. I just do not have the knowledge to properly ask this question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the fadein AFTER you set the picture.
Give that a try and let us know if it helped

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried what you suggested within `imagePreview.click(function(){`. When the page loads, clicking on the preview image pops up the full size, which is desired, but as soon as you click a thumbnail to update the preview image, and click the newly updated preview image, the pop up full size image no longer works